# logout first logged in user if second user try to login for same browser sung angular

Tags: angularjs, session

i am working on one web application in which i want (for same role) logout first use when second user try login for same browser.I have tried cookies for that but i don't get solution.

Comment: browser cookies are the best way to do such things. check in cookies if user   logged in then do forcefully logged out and clear cookies for for logged in user so it will allowed to you for do relogin

Comment: Clear the cookies, localStorage and sessionStorage data in the top of the first controller you invoked. And check a condition where if the user details storage is empty, redirect to the login page. I hope it will help.